# laravel run a route or method of controller via cli

Tags: php, unix, laravel, command-line-interface

I have one website url which takes a long time to run.

It is added in route but want to run it via terminal. This route call a moethod from my controller. as routes does not has php extension so this route will not able to run via php command.

How can I run a laravel route via terminal/CLI.

route :

```
 Route::get('backup', array(
            'uses' => 'DocBackupsController@backup'
        ));
```

what will be my terminal command for it.

I have got solution for it
1) create laravel command using following command

```
php artisan command:make BackupThemeCommand
```

2) Above command will create app/commands/BackupThemeCommand.php file with few contents. update following content to this file, set name using colon to  a artisan command.

```
protected $name = 'backup:theme';
```

3) Add following content to a fire method of above created file and save the file.

```
$obj = new DocBackupsController();
                $obj->backup();
```

4) Add following line to app/start/artisan.php

```
Artisan::add(new BackupThemeCommand);
```

5) call above command using terminal

```
sudo php artisan backup:theme
```

This will let you run a code from terminal..

Comment: You can use `curl` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantiate the `DocBackupsController` object and call the `backup()` method from within some cli script. You are using dependency injection yeah?